# Check if any buttons are clicked

Tags: android, button, dynamic, listener

I have rows of buttons. When the user click on a button, before I do something, how can I check if the user has already clicked and selected any buttons in other rows? If they selected buttons in other rows, do some error, otherwise, call method that selects button. I put stars where I am confused. Thank you for your help.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (****buttonSelected in other rows) {
        ****do something
        } else {
        ButtonClicked(column, row);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There are a bazillion ways to do this. Simplest would likely be to create a resource id to boolean or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

May this code do some help for you.

Take a global variable

```
      boolean anyButtonClicked=false;


button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (anyButtonClicked) {
        ****do something
        } else {
        anyButtonClicked=true;
        ButtonClicked(column, row);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and let you know if I have trouble. Thank you again.